# Confused with which word I should use , "emit" or "emits"

Tags: verbs

> Increasing number of factories built by the TNCs in different parts of the world also **"*emit/emits*"** large quantities of greenhouse gases.

I've read in many articles, factories-emits sounds more natural, can I get some explanations on how this works.

Comment: The factories (plural), not the number (singular), are emitting those gases, so I'd use the plural verb "emit". I don't think "emits" sounds more natural; in fact, it sounds simply wrong to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A number of questions "has been" or "have been" asked?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5378/a-number-of-questions-has-been-or-have-been-asked)

Comment: Rebornify, if you try to explain in detail what makes you think *factories-emits sounds more natural*, you will almost certainly either answer your own question, or realize where your confusion lies.

Either way when you've *read in many articles…* roughly how many is that and loosely, what did two or three of the most typical actually say, please?